# Using fscanf to fill a structure array

Tags: arrays, c, file, struct

So the issue I'm having is on line 152 it only fills emp[1] and it fills it with the data from emp[5]. The program functions as expected everywhere else. I'm learning c now and this would be my first time using fscanf. Included the entire code in case I've made other errors people would like to point out.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


struct employee
{
    int id;
    char name[20];
    int salary;
    int age;
};


void getinfo(struct employee *);
void printinfo(struct employee *);
int searchinfo(struct employee *ptr);
void totalsal(struct employee *ptr);

int main(void)
{
    struct employee emp[5];
    char ms, ms1;
    int selemp, i;
    FILE *outfile;
    FILE *infile;


    printf("In this program we will be allowing the input of 5 sets of employee data.\n");
    do //menu
    {
        printf("Main Menu\n");
        printf("a.Populate.\n");
        printf("b.Print.\n");
        printf("c.Search by ID# and print.\n");
        printf("d.Print total salaries.\n");
        printf("e.Edit structure.\n");
        printf("f.Save to file\n");
        printf("g.Load and print file\n");
        printf("h.Exit\n");
        printf("Please enter an option from the main menu: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%c", &ms);

        switch (ms)
        {
        case 'a':
            getinfo(emp);
            printf("To continue press enter.\n");
            fflush(stdin);
            getchar();
            break;
        case 'b':
            printinfo(emp);
            printf("To continue press enter\n");
            fflush(stdin);
            getchar();
            break;
        case 'c':
            selemp = searchinfo(emp);
            printf("To continue press enter.\n");
            fflush(stdin);
            getchar();
            break;
        case 'd':
            totalsal(emp);
            printf("To continue press enter.\n");
            fflush(stdin);
            getchar();
            break;
        case 'e':
            do
            {
                printf("Editing Menu\n");
                printf("a.Search by ID# and select.\n");
                printf("b.Print selected.\n");
                printf("c.Edit Name.\n");
                printf("d.Edit Salary.\n");
                printf("e.Edit Age.\n");
                printf("f.Exit\n");
                printf("Please enter an option from the menu: ");
                fflush(stdin);
                scanf("%c", &ms1);
                switch (ms1)
                {
                case 'a':
                    selemp = searchinfo(emp);
                    printf("To continue press enter\n");
                    fflush(stdin);
                    getchar();
                    break;
                case 'b':
                    printf("ID: %d\n", emp[selemp].id);
                    printf("Name: %s\n", emp[selemp].name);
                    printf("Salary: %d\n", emp[selemp].salary);
                    printf("Age: %d\n", emp[selemp].age);
                    printf("To continue press enter\n");
                    break;
                case 'c':
                    printf("Enter Name: ");
                    scanf("%s", emp[selemp].name);
                    printf("To continue press enter.\n");
                    break;
                case 'd':
                    printf("Enter salary: ");
                    scanf("%d", &emp[selemp].salary);
                    printf("To continue press enter.\n");
                    break;
                case 'e':
                    printf("Enter age: ");
                    scanf("%d", &emp[selemp].age);
                    printf("To continue press enter.\n");
                    break;
                case 'f':
                    break;
                }
                printf("To continue press enter.\n");
                fflush(stdin);
                getchar();
            }
            while (ms1 != 'f');
            break;
        case 'f':
            outfile = fopen("employee_data.dat", "w");
            if (outfile == NULL)
            {
                printf("\nFile not Found\n");
                break;
            }
            for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                fwrite(&emp[i], sizeof(struct employee), 1, outfile);
            }
            if (fwrite != 0) printf("File written successfully.\n");
            else printf("Error writing file!\n");

            fclose(outfile);
            break;
        case 'g':
            infile = fopen("employee_data.dat", "r");
            if (infile == NULL)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "\nError opening file\n");
                break;
            }
            for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                while (fread(&emp[i], sizeof(struct employee), 1, infile)) printf("ID# = %d\nName = %s\nSalary = %d\nAge = %d\n", emp[i].id, emp[i].name, emp[i].salary, emp[i].age);
            }
            rewind(infile);
            for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                fscanf(infile, "%d %s %d %d", &emp[i].id, emp[i].name, &emp[i].salary, &emp[i].age);
            }
            printf("To continue press enter.\n");
            fflush(stdin);
            getchar();
            fclose(infile);
            break;
        case 'h':
            exit(0);
            break;
        default:
            printf("Invalid Input\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    while (ms != 'h');
    return 0;
}

void getinfo(struct employee *ptr) //function for filling structured array
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter detail of employee #%d\n", (i + 1));
        printf("Enter ID#: ");
        scanf("%d", &ptr->id);
        printf("Enter Name: ");
        scanf("%s", ptr->name);
        printf("Enter salary: ");
        scanf("%d", &ptr->salary);
        printf("Enter age: ");
        scanf("%d", &ptr->age);
        ptr++;
    }

}

void printinfo(struct employee *ptr) //function for printing structure
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("\nDetail of employee #%d\n", (i + 1));
        printf("ID: %d\n", ptr->id);
        printf("Name: %s\n", ptr->name);
        printf("Salary: %d\n", ptr->salary);
        printf("Age: %d\n", ptr->age);
        ptr++;
    }
}

int searchinfo(struct employee *ptr)
{
    int i, id1;
    printf("Enter ID# to search for:");
    scanf("%d", &id1);

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (id1 == ptr->id)
        {
            printf("ID# found\n");
            printf("\nDetail of employee #%d\n", (i + 1));
            printf("ID: %d\n", ptr->id);
            printf("Name: %s\n", ptr->name);
            printf("Salary: %d\n", ptr->salary);
            printf("Age: %d\n", ptr->age);
            return i;
        } else
        {
            ptr++;
        }
    }
    printf("ID# not found\n");
    return 0;
}

void totalsal(struct employee *ptr)
{
    int i, sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        sum = ptr->salary + sum;
        ptr++;
    }
    printf("Salary total: %d\n", sum);
}
```

Comment: Your first loop at line 146 appears to read all the data in already. Then your next loop tries to read it in again (I'm not sure why that's needed), but you didn't reset the file pointer to the beginning of the file. Unless your intention is to read employee records 6-10 from the file.

Comment: Adding rewind(infile); between the loops had no impact on the issue though, it still filled emp[1] with the info for emp[5]

Comment: Have you independently confirmed the file contains the expected data in the correct order?

Comment: I'm using the code on line 130 to fill the file and the code on 148 prints all sets with proper data.

Comment: Avoid making changes to the code you originally posted here. Add additional code blocks if/when it's absolutely necessary to drive the discussion to a conclusion. Otherwise, you're changing line numbers and folks who are trying to assist you get out of sync.

Comment: Ahhh noted, my bad, wont do that in the future.

Comment: Also, it would be good if you could include a response file to feed into your program, to reproduce the problem. These school / learn C projects often require a good bit of manual user input to set things up to drill into the problem. It's easier if we can just set a few break-points and pipe a file into the program.  Also, have you actually stepped into the program and looked at the state of your variables near/at the point of failure?

Comment: Just ran through step by step and everything looks accurate until line 154 where it seems to overwrite emp[1] with the data from all elements in the array.

Comment: I suspect your results would be a bit clearer if you constrained the width when reading employee name. Haven't checked yet, but there's probably a missing nul character somewhere, causing an overwrite. It will be easier to find, or might even go away if you do this: `struct employee emp[5] = {0}'. Bugs, particularly buffer overruns and wild pointers, tend to feed and have overlapping effects on each other.

Answer (score 1):

I think @lurker's comment nailed it, but I would also add the following, which would not fit in a comment:

```
D:\Playground\C\C\Source.c(45): warning C6031: Return value ignored: 'scanf'.
D:\Playground\C\C\Source.c(53): warning C6031: Return value ignored: 'getchar'.
D:\Playground\C\C\Source.c(59): warning C6031: Return value ignored: 'getchar'.
D:\Playground\C\C\Source.c(65): warning C6031: Return value ignored: 'getchar'.
D:\Playground\C\C\Source.c(71): warning C6031: Return value ignored: 'getchar'.
D:\Playground\C\C\Source.c(85): warning C6031: Return value ignored: 'scanf'.
D:\Playground\C\C\Source.c(92): warning C6031: Return value ignored: 'getchar'.
D:\Playground\C\C\Source.c(103): warning C6031: Return value ignored: 'scanf'.
D:\Playground\C\C\Source.c(108): warning C6031: Return value ignored: 'scanf'.
D:\Playground\C\C\Source.c(113): warning C6031: Return value ignored: 'scanf'.
D:\Playground\C\C\Source.c(121): warning C6031: Return value ignored: 'getchar'.
D:\Playground\C\C\Source.c(153): warning C6031: Return value ignored: 'fscanf'.
D:\Playground\C\C\Source.c(157): warning C6031: Return value ignored: 'getchar'.
D:\Playground\C\C\Source.c(95): warning C6001: Using uninitialized memory 'emp'.
D:\Playground\C\C\Source.c(95): warning C6001: Using uninitialized memory 'selemp'.
D:\Playground\C\C\Source.c(149): warning C6387: 'infile' could be '0':  this does not adhere to the specification for the function 'fread'. 
D:\Playground\C\C\Source.c(153): warning C6387: 'infile' could be '0':  this does not adhere to the specification for the function 'fscanf'. See line 149 for an earlier location where this can occur
D:\Playground\C\C\Source.c(158): warning C6387: 'infile' could be '0':  this does not adhere to the specification for the function 'fclose'. See line 149 for an earlier location where this can occur
D:\Playground\C\C\Source.c(179): warning C6031: Return value ignored: 'scanf'.
D:\Playground\C\C\Source.c(181): warning C6031: Return value ignored: 'scanf'.
D:\Playground\C\C\Source.c(183): warning C6031: Return value ignored: 'scanf'.
D:\Playground\C\C\Source.c(185): warning C6031: Return value ignored: 'scanf'.
D:\Playground\C\C\Source.c(210): warning C6031: Return value ignored: 'scanf'.
```

And I would suggest that you adopt the habit of composing your applications out of many more smaller functions than what you have. Generally, a function that has more than five  statements, is a candidate for scrutiny. Any with over 12 non-switch-case statements, should be broken up. If you have more than a few switch-case blocks, then you should move the implementations of each of those blocks into individual functions to provide more clarity.

---

Here you are potentially continuing to use `infile` after detecting it is NULL.

```
            if (infile == NULL)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "\nError opening file\n");
                // Should break, continue or exit here.
                // Should not fall-through.
            }
```

---

Your program allows the user to attempt to read a data file that hasn't been saved! During your many code/build/test cycles, there's likely to be detritus laying around on your file system that can taint later tests.

---

You have a couple of magic numbers in your code:

```
char name[20];
...
struct employee emp[5];
```

You repeat one of them many times in your code with `for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)`. This makes modifications to your program tedious and error prone. Use constants instead:

```
#define MAX_NAME_LEN 20
#define MAX_EMPLOYEES 5
...
char name[MAX_NAME_LEN];
...
struct employee emp[MAX_EMPLOYEES];
...
char nameFormat[11] = {0};
if (!(sprintf(nameFormat, "%%%is", MAX_NAME_LEN-1)>0)) {/*Handle the error*/};
...
for (i = 0; i < MAX_EMPLOYEES; i++)
...
if (scanf(nameFormat, emp[selemp].name)<1) {/*Handle the error*/};
```

---

When you witness a program misbehaving, never assume you have just one bug. This is particularly true for newbs and anyone who writes more than one line of untested code at a time. In other words, most of us. You definitely had the obvious `rewind` issue, but you have weak code that allows buffer overruns and does not ensure that buffers written to the output file, are properly initialized. So when you fixed the `rewind` problem, you still had failures and immediately assumed that wasn't the problem. The fact is, it was one of them, and now you're still trying to tease out where the bugs are.

This is where code hygiene pays off. Always zero initialize buffers before use, and you'll have an easier time spotting issues in your debugging sessions. Always check function return values, and you won't miss obvious failures you should have caught much earlier. These things feed on each other. The root cause of many bugs, is often hidden by the many other bugs in your code.

Write small functions, that you can test independently of the rest of the program. It's probably exceedingly rare, but teachers should show you how to write unit tests first, then work up to functional programs. When your program is built from tested parts, it's a lot easier to isolate and fix bugs.

Comment: @Duller I spotted it because I had warnings dialed up and they told me that `infile` could be 0 in several places where it was being used. What compiler are you using?

Comment: Beginners should set warnings as errors. I seem to recall that `-Wall` dials up the warning levels. Just get in the habit of treating all warnings as if they are errors. Always fix all warnings before you ask for help. We shouldn't have to slog through that mess, when you can so easily resolve them before hand.

Comment: I agree with all points, I have a copy that I'm cleaning, so far I have initialized the array to 0, added the constants, added the rewind and fixed the missing break. As well as the only warning that the compiler is showing is on line 136 stating that the comparison will always evaluate as true. However I'm not sure were you're implying the use of char nameFormat.

Comment: When you read the name from the user or the file, you need a width specifier `%20s`. Converting that to use the compile time constant requires you to create the format specifier at run-time. Hence the `nameFormat`.  You only need to create that once, at the top of your program, then reuse it anywhere you are reading input into the name buffer. It will prevent the input function from overwriting the rest of your data structures if  what's on disk isn't properly NULL terminated. Hmm... I gave you an off by error as well...

Comment: There. Updated `if (!(sprintf(nameFormat, "%%%is", MAX_NAME_LEN-1)>0)) {/*Handle the error*/};` to leave room for the terminating nul character.  Old C programmer's joke goes something like: There's three things that are hard in C programming; 1) naming things and 2) avoiding off by one errors. ;)